# Creating a Message-Hub Bridge for IBM Cloud Object Storage

Tags: object-storage, message-hub, ibm-cloud-storage

I'm trying to create a "Bridge" from Message Hub to S3 Object Storage, copying information from the credentials that I created but I always get an error that says "**Please trying refreshing the page, or logging back into Bluemix.**"

I have already created an access policy for these credentials and the Bucket I want to use as destination.

Also tried with private and public end-points.
I wasn't able to found documentation that explains how to accomplish this. Nothing seems to work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apologies, this is an internal error caused by the S3 Object Storage bridges capability being made available in the UI but not in the backend.

An update to the Message Hub service will be made this week to correct this.